# Dynamic substitute variable

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm looking to find out if it is possible for substitute variables to be 'dynamic'.

For example, I want to use a popup for a repeatable script that prompts the user to enter two variables: colour and number. However, I need the script to still run even if the user does not enter one variable. In other words it sets the variable to IS NOT NULL if left blank.

Is this even possible?

```
select user
from table
where colour = '&colour'
and number = &number
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really something Oracle is meant to do (substitution variables are generally just for quick ad-hoc things, and serious reporting should be handled on the front-end).

As a bit of a hack, you could do something like this:

```
select user
from table
where (colour = '&&colour' OR '&&colour' IS NULL)
  and (number = to_number('&&number') OR to_number('&&number') IS NULL);
```

Just as a side-note, I was a bit surprised to find that the empty string is treated as `NULL` in Oracle.

Apparently, `'' IS NULL` evaluates to true, and `'' = ''` evaluates to false (which makes sense, since any equality check to `NULL` is false)

Comment: if you [use `&&` instead of `&`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-C6BE6E41-821F-413E-B4B1-56AAE4A46298) you'll only be prompted for the variables once. (Also, the documentation has [a section about nulls](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/Nulls.html) that covers your last two paragraphs *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks, I added that to the answer (I'm using PL/SQL Developer, where that's the default behavior for just a single `&`)

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of queries, I always use the nvl function; example as folows:

```
select user
from table
where colour = nvl('&colour', colour)
and number = nvl(&number,number)
;
```